# Is it illegal to implement a patented algorithm or method and take advantage from it?

Tags: patents

I have been working on an SW project that combines image processing and IMU data since 2019. (Mobile platform)

Unfortunately, a company got a patent on the same method that I have been working on and started selling their product last year (2020).

Seems like the only way is to make a free version of my software and get profit out of advertisements. Will it be illegal? Or is there a better way to avoiding patent infringement?

Open-sourcing is the last option and if I do that it will be to add one more line to my CV without getting any profit out of the project.

Comment: Your best bet is to show *prior art*, document that you shared or published the code before the date of their patent application.  *Or really, that **anyone** did*.  If you can't, then talk to your university ethics people about what you do about that situation - you don't want to be accused of plagiarizing their patent!

Comment: Combining image processing and IMU data does not seem a novel idea. Did they patent the combination of the two things in a generic manner or a very specific method to do so? First of all you have to read carefully the patent and understand what it covers exactly. If it is a very generic patent you may search for research papers trying to do similar things. You may find some prior art that you could use to invalidate the patent. Remember that here the devil and the lawyer is in the very small details.

Comment: Note that "open source" does _not_ imply "free of charge". You can give away your project for free without making it open source and you can make it open source and still sell it. You just need to distribute the source code and not just a compiled binary, but there is no reason you can't charge. The only issue (which can indeed be a problem) is that you cannot stop someone who buys it from you to then make a copy that they distribute for free.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### You cannot use a patented invention without permission

A patent gives the owner **exclusive** rights to use it: not just profit from it. The only way you can use their patent is by licensing it.

You cannot make any version of the software that uses the patented method, free or otherwise. Technically, the software you have now is infringing even if you never release it.

If you had published your work before they filed for the patent, you can seek to have their patent invalidated due to the existence of [prior art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_art). If you had been using it privately prior to this some jurisdictions will allow you to keep using it privately.

Comment: @EricDuminil Indeed. If you look back at old documents around what the point of patents were and what could and couldn't be patented, among those things that couldn't be patented were: math and clothing. Math because it was considered a part of nature and clothing because it was so ubiquitous. But I can't imagine anything more ubiquitous in this day and age than software. There's more people writing their own code than people making their own clothes these days. And ultimately software *is* just math.

Comment: Do I read you (and the Wikipedia article on patents) right that it is even forbidden to privately implement the patented algorithm *per se?* That is, without ever using the resulting program (beyond, say, a test), let alone "taking advantage" from it? (Of course, detection and enforcement are a different matter -- strictly formal law question.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - The enforcement aspect is however crucial, because patent infringement is not defined to be a crime.  The patent holder can request you to stop making infringing software, but if you haven't impacted their reputation or economic interests (for which they could request a remedy), they don't have much of a leverage over your private research actions.  Worst case, you'll cease and desist when asked to.

Comment: @Shufflepants Do you have a citation for clothing not being patentable originally? It definitely is now, and as far as I can tell, it always has been.

Comment: @Shufflepants - how ubiquitous something is has no relation to patentablity. Regarding your assertion about clothing - in the USPTO classification system Apparel is 2 and has been since 1923. And can you turn a bunch of transistors into a smart phone by adding equations?

Comment: @jcaron In the U.S. anyone can file an Inter Partes Review to try to get a patent invalidated on the basis of prior art and in most of the rest of the world anyone can file an opposition to a recently granted patent.  It isn't that B *had* prior art, it's the the prior art was published.

Comment: @Shufflepants You can't patent a mathematical formula, but you can patent the *application* of a formula, which is precisely why software is patentable.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - a patent gives the owner the right to try to stop others from making, selling, offering for sale, importing or using something that infringes one or more claims.

Comment: @everyone Yes, I'm aware that design patents for fashion and software patents are a thing now. But this was not always so. The first design patents weren't granted until 1842 https://www.ipwatchdog.com/2014/01/11/design-patent-history/id=47283/ and there has been much argumentation in court cases over whether software is just math https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/409/63/ Even now, not everything about an article of clothing is patentable. This is why knockoffs of things that don't pretend to be a certain brand are still often legal so long as you don't violate trademark.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie but does that necessarily mean an algorithm is patentable?  I always assumed that in the same way an idea alone isn't patentable (afaik), an algorithm isn't patentable either.  Rather, only a specific implementation/application of an algorithm is patentable.  In that case, might OP be fine if they do things at all differently from the patent holders?

Comment: @CCJ: Algorithms are a complicated mess. The most recent word from the Supreme Court is *Alice v. CLS Bank*, which is, frankly, not a very helpful opinion in sorting out what the law is. See also *Mayo v. Prometheus* and *Bilski v. Kappos* for additional background; the latter in particular really helped to precipitate this confusion.

Comment: @Shufflepants There is no specific restriction on the patentability of the design of clothes apart from the fact that almost all useful aspects of designs have already been done before. The non-useful aspects of design either go under design patent (which is hard to get unless you invent something completely new) or copyright. There is however a restriction on copyrighting fashion and cooking recipes and indeed the US congress gave as a reason for the restriction the fact that clothing and food are too useful to allow to be copyrighted. You can however copyright fashion in France

Comment: @Shufflepants .. the restriction on COPYRIGHTING fashion and recipes is more about their UTILITY instead of UBIQUITY. The USA has not always been ultra-consumerist-capitalist

Comment: This answer seems very one-sided. As Marco has shown, software is not patentable; so it may be that the patent is invalid. Then of course there arises the question whether OP expects the company to still try to enforce; and whether he is able and willing to go to court...

Comment: @DaleM -  good answer with one nit. A patent does not give the owner the right to practice it - it is a negative right, the right to try to keep others from practicing it. A broader patent or government regulation might keep a patent owner from being able to practice their own patent.

Comment: @Shufflepants - The classification system for patents has these low number classes - for* utility* patents -    002 Apparel
   004 Baths, closets, sinks, and spittoons
   005 Beds
   007 Compound tools
   008 Bleaching and dyeing; fluid treatment and chemical modification of textiles and fibers
   012 Boot and shoe making
   014 Bridges
   015 Brushing, scrubbing, and general cleaning Apparel is right up there with spittoons, beds and boots.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite not so - patents can be cancelled for non-use.

Comment: There is no "working" requirement in the U.S. or EPO. A few countries, like India, have a requirement to "work" a patent. If a patent isn't licensed or the item is not manufactured for sale in India, Sri Lanka or Australia the government can grant a compulsory license to a third party. the patent owner get a "reasonable" royalty.

Comment: Completely separate is what I was trying to correct - from Wikipedia  "A patent does not give a right to make or use or sell an invention. Rather, a patent provides, from a legal standpoint, the right to exclude others from making, using, selling, offering for sale, or importing the patented invention for the term of the patent, which is usually 20 years from the filing date subject to the payment of maintenance fees." Many patents cover improvements to something that is, in turn, already patented by someone else. Without permission of the base patent owner you can't make your patented thing.

Comment: That is is a right to exclude rather than the right to do something is fundamental to patent law everywhere.  Get a patent on an improvement to an iPhone and try to say that means you can make one.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the question:

- as there is a patent and you believe it to be valid, it is illegal to use the patented invention.
- it is totally irrelevant if you make any money on the invention or not, the use is exclusively for the patent holder (or licenced users).
- but, well, the bad consequences will occur if the patent holder finds out and actually cares.

I believe there are five parts, or maybe phases, to the question about patents. The steps are mostly consistent around the world although the details may vary.

1. Getting a patent

There is a process where a person or a company may ask for and be given the exclusive rights to a patentable "invention" for a specific territory and a specific time. It includes describing what is to be patented and paying the relevant fees. The patent authority, granting the patent, does a bit of research including trying to check for patentability and finding "prior art", that is if this is already patented or perhaps generally known through a publication. In different countries this checking may be more or less thorough, I believe that the US patent office is known to be less strict than in some other countries. Once the patent is granted it is published. (Sometimes companies avoid creating patents as the secrets are then published).

2. Using the patented "invention"

The idea is that the patent holder has the exclusive right to use the patented invention for a limited time. This is only relevant for the territory where the patent is granted, as example, a US Patent might not automatically be valid in France. No person, may use the patented invention without permission of the patent holder. There are a few exceptions to this, but the infringing party then is generally governments or international organizations (examples include some medicines, or the way AIS data is sent between ships).

3. Stopping patent infringement

The patent holder will try to stop others from using the patented invention. This might start with a "stop and cease order" with wordings warning of dire consequences. Often the idea is to be frightening enough to not have to go to court. It might escalate to going to court and asking for damages. It is generally up to the patent holder to initiate this action, although at times authorities or border forces or such might do it on their own. Border forces are sometimes instructed to look for "counterfeit" brand products punishing the consumer buying these products.

4. Going to court

The typical situation is that there will be less probability for a court proceeding the less money the defendant has. Sometimes in the US law system the civil layers will take cases on a percentage of the eventual penalties (this is not allowed in some jurisdictions), one reason why they aim for astronomical sums. But if the defendant has no money, the "ambulance chasers" will not take the case.

5. Trying to disprove the patent

It is not uncommon for the patent to be proven "not valid" in the court process. If the defendant can show "prior art", the patent was invalid from the start. If it can be shown that the patent in a specific case was not relevant for the actual usage it will also be rejected by the court.

So, you might want to take your chances. Maybe the patent can be proven to be non-valid if you can find prior art? If not, it will be illegal, and could become costly.

Comment: Good answer except "might not automatically be valid in France" could be read to indicate that *sometimes* a U.S. patent is recognized in France (using your example). No, there is no case where a U.S. patent is "recognized" by another country. Of course the inventor can file in as many counties as they have money to do. Some might grant it and some might not.